# Linked Objects, Drivers and Animation of custom Properties

Tags: animation, properties, drivers, linked-data

I have created an Object with some Shape Keys. To simplify the planned Animation, I have created four custom Properties on that object and connected some drivers, so that the change of one Property effects multiple values of the Key Shapes.

That does all work as expected is seems to be pretty nice! But I would like to use that object in an Animation where it should appear two times. So I created a new Blender File and linked that object two times and made a proxy out of each.

In Summary: One File, containing two proxies, linking to one Object in another file.

When I try to animate these properties, It happens that no matter which of both I select, all the key frames are created for the second object I have linked. Except for one Property.

In Curve Editor (Animation View), the curves to edit are always the ones of the Object that is not selected.

Am I facing an error here, or do I have anything missed? Is it possible to do what I would like to, or can't that be done with linking?

Any Help appreciated! Thanks in ahead!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you manage to find the issue? And it even gets messier with three or more proxies. Blender never seems to find the right target.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is not supported yet in blender. to bring in the same object multiple times you need to save the object again as another copy and import that separately...

people have answered this here:
[multiple copys of character with rig linked in the same file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97694/multiple-copys-of-character-with-rig-linked-in-the-same-file)