# multiple copys of character with rig linked in the same file

Tags: rigging, armature, linked-data, displacement

This question has been asked before, here: [Link blend multiple times](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74589/link-blend-multiple-times)

But the question is almost a year old, and there is no answer. How do I link multiple copies of the same character in a scene und make their armatures local ("make proxy"), without double influences?

I added the character using *link -> character group*. Then I make the rig local by *"make proxy" -> character rig group*.

[image]

Maybe this is worth a seperate question, but I will add it here too (it might be a related issue):
The micropolygon displacement is also not working on the linked meshes. I really would like that to work, too.

Comment: The first comment there still applies

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that is really sad to hear, I hoped the 2.79 update might have adresse it somehow. do you know a workaround? the only viable solution for me would ensure a link to the "master file".

Comment: Only workaround I know is to make an independent copy of the armature

Comment: Please use a new post for each additional question.

Answer (score 2):

This is something Blender can't help you with yet.

Solution is to have duplicates for each instance you wish to link:

- objects can share mesh data, so update to one mesh changes all
- armatures have to be independent objects

It is smart to have scripts to update all other armatures or modifiers when you do changes to one of those so it's not that time consuming.